# Passing and receiving dictionary of dictionary of parameters

Tags: python, objective-c, dictionary, http-post

Using AFNetworking, In my iPhone application I'd like to pass in the NSDictionary of parameters a dictionary of parameters like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int courseIdx=0; courseIdx < courses.count; courseIdx++)
{
   parameters[courseIdx] = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   parameters[courseIdx]["courseID"] = courses[courseIdx].courseID;
   parameters[courseIdx]["courseRate"] = courses[courseIdx].courseRate;
   parameters[courseIdx]["profRate"] = courses[courseIdx].profRate;
}
```

then on the server side using python I'd like to extract these parameters... once I extract the dictionary (or Array of Dictionaries) I know how to extract the values...**The Problem** I don't know how to extract the inner dictionaries from the exterior on so I'd be able to run in a loop

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   request_data=json.loads(request.POST['request'])
   ????
   for param_data in ???
      course_id = param_data['courseID']
      ...
```

Comment: What is wrong with nesting loops in loops?

Comment: @HermannKlecker nothing wrong i just need the line to extract the data for the external loop (please add the code instead of ????)

Comment: How is the data being passed from iOS to Python? Is the POST form-urlencoded or is it strict JSON?